# Pop open WPF Menu control programmatically

Tags: wpf, menu

I'd like to open a WPF Menu when handling a click on a separate control. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
myMenu.IsSubmenuOpen = true;
```

where myMenu is the name of the menu you want to open.

Comment: Strictly, this isn't applicable to the Menu control, but to MenuItem controls. As my Menu is bound to a data source, this isn't straightforward. I've figured that the top level MenuItem can be retrieved with MyMenu.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as MenuItem from which I can then use the IsSubMenuOpen property. As you gave me the lead I needed, I'll award you the accept.